# Typing methods that are needed to work with results from GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm having a headless CMS that generates all the types for my GraphQL schema.

After executing the query I get a result I can work with. The result contains an array.

When I need to use the filter, map or find method on an array returned from the server I get a Property 'filter/map/find' does not exist on type 'TypeName'

There is a quick fix for that through Visual Studio, but it adds the types in an automatic generated file. My solution was to extend the types in a separate file and that works

```
import { DataEntity } from './__generated__/graphql'

interface DataEntityWithMethods extends DataEntity {
    filter(arg0?: (grouping: DataEntity) => DataEntity): unknown
    find(arg0?: (group: DataEntity) => boolean): unknown
    map(arg0?: (group: DataEntity) => void): unknown
}

export type { DataEntityWithMethods }
```

But is this the best approach? I found it strange that I need to add the default JS methods to the types created.

Is this how TypeScript works?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `DataEntity[]`?

Comment: @vera. I think that is the correct way of doing it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No!

When you set the type of a variable containing an array you need to add [] behind it to tell TypeScript its an array and not and Object.

Like this:

```
let data: DataEntity[]
```

If you do that, you don't need to register any methods for the object.

Pay attention to that TypeScript doesn't recognize the problem in the first place and suggests a quick fix that is an incorrect way of handling the issue.